# Do a consumable iOS product REQUIRE restore functionality, and if so, is there a way to do so without a server?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing a game with Unity.

Say a player can buy 5x arrows for 0.99$. Do I have to provide the user the ability to restore the unused arrows in order to not be rejected by the AppStore?

I know they say that, if I want to provide the restoration functionality, I have to use my own servers... is there a way to store the amount of arrows a player have without the need of using my own server?

sorry for the offtopic, I really don't have anywhere else to ask :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com and this site does not appear on the network when selecting the right option

Comment: I am not sure how to close my question... anyway, as there might be other users who considered it useful, this question has already been answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327800/do-a-consumable-ios-product-require-restore-functionality it is a very complete answer, would recommend to read it :)